# How do I create a unique id for every new visitor?

Tags: php, scripting, uuid

my question is how do create a unique id (which will go at the end of the URL, e.g. http://example.com/?id=12345) for every unique visitor who visits my site. I am also wondering how to track the visitors ip address, so that they only receive one id/link. In other words, how to make a script which generates one unique id per IP address. In short, I want a script which generates a unique ID for every new visitor. So for example: visitor 1's id=http://example.com/?id=12345, visitor 2's id=http://example.com/?id=77369, and so on. Thanks.

Comment: What are you tracking that's so important that a duplicate is fatal, yet not important enough to force users to just register and log in? BTW, if you actually care about your data, you don't stick it on a URL...

Answer (score 6):

Easiest thing might just be to use [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php).

```
 session_start();
 $id = session_id();
```

You can then save off $id and associate it with whatever you want in a database or whatever.

Alternative, just save off a very accurate timestamp in microseconds

```
$id = microtime();
```

Or create a row in a database per user and use the primary key of the row.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I incorporate it into a website? Sorry, I'm really new to php :(

Comment: Imho it is too expensive operation - to start session if you actually don't need it.

Comment: you lost parameter for microtime. Also iirc modern regular hardware is not possible to resolve time to microseconds so the latest digits are unreliable.

Comment: Thanks Doug T. Your answer helped me to get around showing part of the IP-address frontend as an identificator, instead I show part of the session id now!

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers can be incorporated simply enough. However, something you may not have thought about is what happens when more than one user shares an IP. For example, all of the employees at Google or all of the users at AOL or Juno may use 100 ips among all of them. What if they are served new IPs every 10 - 25 days.

The idea behind data is that is is meaningful. How will your data be meaningful? The IP could be a 12 year old kid from upstate New York one day and a 40 year old women from Hackensack New Jersey the next. What good does it do you to implement such a system besides complicating your code?

**My Advice:** Revisit your requirements. What are you really trying to accomplish? It may be better to implement a simple cookie to track unique visitors. It still won't be 100% accurate (what about the people who visit from internet cafe's all paying to use the same computer?). But it would make the code much less complicated not having to append every url with all of the extra parameters.

In short, the only way to ensure a unique ID per visitor is bay asking them to login. Granted they could potentially set up multiple accounts using different email addresses, but at least you are guaranteed that no two separate people will get the same id.

Comment: collecting ips can show where the majority of users are coming from(eg. city, country). even though not 100%, still can be useful

Answer (score 3):

How about creating something very unique like this?

```php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$m_time = microtime();
    
$unique_id = md5($ip . $m_time . rand(0, time()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok that you probably will get duplicate after several millions (or 100Ms, who knows) - then the simplest way is to use `uniqid('', true)`

If not - then create some sequence in database and increment it for each new user.

Comment: Unfortunatley, I can't risk duplicates :(

Comment: @user716354: I've written my answer for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents are to use SQL table of pairs: [id, ip].
Making sure that your access to the data base is "atomic".
That is, no one can get in between your read & optional write to the database.
for [more reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)
get(ip) will return the id if exists
or will generate a new entry and will return the new id (simple +1 method).

I can think of many variations to the above.
Bottom line: use *simple* sql table with simple incremental method.